# Perpendicular line from bezier curve to point

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry, intersection, bezier, cubic-bezier

## Question

I need to get the **the point *Q* of a cubic (2d) bezier curve** *B(t)* where the line from point *Q* to another given point *P* **intersects perpendicular** with the bezier curve.

- I know: *P*, *B(t)*
- I look for: *Q* (basically I want to have the slope of *g* but I can easily calculate this when I know *Q*, but the slope of *g* is enough)

[image]

---

### What I did until now (you can skip this)

> Note that I think this ansatz is wrong. This is only included for completeness.

I tried to solve this with my (basic) knowledge of mathematics but I cannot finish it. This is what I have now (please don't too strict with the notation, I'm not very good in this):

The following formulas will be expressed as *y(x)* to get one result this has to be calculated for *y(x)* **and** *x(y)*. The point *P* is the control point, *Q* is the point where the line *g(x)* from *Q* to *P* is perpendicular on the bezier curve ***B**(t) = (x, y)<sup>T</sup>*. The expression for the line *g(x)* can be retrieved by

[image]

where *B(x)* is the bezier curve in Cartesian coordinates, *B'(x)* the derivative (in Cartesian coordinates) and *k* is the intersection with the y axis. To get the slope of *g(x)* one has to solve

[image]

To calculate *B(x)* one has to solve ***B**(t)* for *t* and then plugging it back in *B(t)*. So in each point on the bezier curve there is the relation

[image]

which also applies for the derivative ***B**'(t)*.

The derivative of ***B**(t)* is (according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#Cubic_B%C3%A9zier_curves))

[image]

Solving this for t ([with wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x+%3D+3+*+%281-t%29%5E2+*+a_0+%2B+6+*+%281-t%29+*+t+*+a_1+%2B+3+*+t%5E2+*+a_2+solve+t)) results in

[image]

where *a<sub>0</sub> = (**P<sub>1</sub>** - **P<sub>0</sub>**)<sub>x</sub>*, *a<sub>1</sub> = (**P<sub>2</sub>** - **P<sub>1</sub>**)<sub>x</sub>* and *a<sub>2</sub> = (**P<sub>3</sub>** - **P<sub>2</sub>**)<sub>x</sub>*. Plugging the *t<sub>i</sub>*s back in ***B**(t)* results in ([wolfram alpha for *t<sub>1</sub>*](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=t%3D-%280.33333+%281.7321+sqrt%28-2+a_1+x+%2B+a_0+%28x+-+3+a_2%29+%2B+a_2+x+%2B+3+a_1%5E2%29+-+3+a_0+%2B+3+a_1%29%29%2F%28a_0+-+2+a_1+%2B+a_2%29+for+y+%3D+3+*+%281-t%29%5E2+*+a_0+%2B+6+*+%281-t%29+*+t+*+a_1+%2B+3+*+t%5E2+*+a_2), [wolfram alpha for *t<sub>2</sub>*](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=t%3D-%280.33333+%281.7321+sqrt%28-2+a_1+x+%2B+a_0+%28x+-+3+a_2%29+%2B+a_2+x+%2B+3+a_1%5E2%29+%2B+3+a_0+-+3+a_1%29%29%2F%28a_0+-+2+a_1+%2B+a_2%29+for+y+%3D+3+*+%281-t%29%5E2+*+a_0+%2B+6+*+%281-t%29+*+t+*+a_1+%2B+3+*+t%5E2+*+a_2), [wolfram alpha for *t<sub>3</sub>*](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=t+%3D+%28-6+a_1+%2B+3+a_2+%2B+x%29%2F%286+%28a_2+-+a_1%29%29+for+y+%3D+3+*+%281-t%29%5E2+*+a_0+%2B+6+*+%281-t%29+*+t+*+a_1+%2B+3+*+t%5E2+*+a_2))

[image]

Now the next thing would be to use *y = B'(x)* and the second equation and eliminate *x* but I have no idea how and I don't even know if this is possible.

Comment: very important technical note: there is no "the point". There can in fact be _many_ points that form a line to P that is perpendicular to the curve. Basing the maths off of the idea that you're trying to find a single point is going to lead to the wrong formulae.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans oh yes, you are right. I didn't even think about that. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a implementation for a approximation for my problem made by [mbostock on Github](https://gist.github.com/mbostock/8027637) who implemented the idea from [this online book which was acutally created by @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans](https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#projections) about bezier curves. If you have to deal with bezier curves check this out. This explains most of the problems I had with bezier curves.

The idea of the algorithm is the following one:

1. Make a rough approximation:

   1. Calculate ***Q***<sub>approx, *i*</sub> by plugging in different *t*<sub>*i*</sub>s in ***B***(*t*) (mbostock uses *t*<sub>1</sub> = 0, *t*<sub>2</sub> = 1/8, *t*<sub>3</sub> = 2/8, ...).
   2. Calculate the quadratic (save one square root calculation) distance between ***Q***<sub>approx, *i*</sub> and ***P***.
   3. Save the ***Q***<sub>approx, *i*</sub> and the *t*<sub>*i*</sub> which is the closest (with the smallest distance).
2. Make a more precise approximation:

   1. Choose a precision *q*.
   2. Calculate *t*<sub>before</sub> = *t*<sub>i</sub> - *q*.
   3. Check if the distance between between ***Q***<sub>approx, before</sub> = ***B***(*t*<sub>before</sub>) and ***P*** is smaller than the distance between ***Q***<sub>approx, *i*</sub> and ***P***, if yes set ***Q***<sub>approx, *i*</sub> = ***Q***<sub>approx, before</sub> and start at 2 (precise approximation), if no continue.
   4. Calculate *t*<sub>after</sub> = *t*<sub>i</sub> + *q*.
   5. Check if the distance between between ***Q***<sub>approx, after</sub> = ***B***(*t*<sub>after</sub>) and ***P*** is smaller than the distance between ***Q***<sub>approx, *i*</sub> and ***P***, if yes set ***Q***<sub>approx, *i*</sub> = ***Q***<sub>after</sub> and start at 2 (precise approximation), if no continue.
   6. ***Q***<sub>approx, *i*</sub> is the closest. If the precision is good enough stop here. If not decrease the precision *q* (mbostock divides by two) and start over again at 2 (precise approximation).

> As already mentioned there is the implementation of [mbostock on Github](https://gist.github.com/mbostock/8027637). I 
>   paste the code here in case the link goes down. THIS IS NOT MY OWN CODE.

```js
var points = [[474,276],[586,393],[378,388],[338,323],[341,138],[547,252],[589,148],[346,227],[365,108],[562,62]];
var width = 960,
    height = 500;
var line = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("cardinal");
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);
var path = svg.append("path")
    .datum(points)
    .attr("d", line);
var line = svg.append("line");
var circle = svg.append("circle")
    .attr("cx", -10)
    .attr("cy", -10)
    .attr("r", 3.5);
svg.append("rect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .on("mousemove", mousemoved);
// adding coordinates display
var coords = svg.append("text");
function mousemoved() {
  var m = d3.mouse(this),
      p = closestPoint(path.node(), m);
  line.attr("x1", p[0]).attr("y1", p[1]).attr("x2", m[0]).attr("y2", m[1]);
  circle.attr("cx", p[0]).attr("cy", p[1]);
  coords.attr("x", (p[0] + m[0]) / 2).attr("y", (p[1] + m[1]) / 2).html("Q(" + Math.round(p[0]) + ", " + Math.round(p[1]) + ")");
}
function closestPoint(pathNode, point) {
  var pathLength = pathNode.getTotalLength(),
      precision = 8,
      best,
      bestLength,
      bestDistance = Infinity;
  // linear scan for coarse approximation
  for (var scan, scanLength = 0, scanDistance; scanLength <= pathLength; scanLength += precision) {
    if ((scanDistance = distance2(scan = pathNode.getPointAtLength(scanLength))) < bestDistance) {
      best = scan, bestLength = scanLength, bestDistance = scanDistance;
    }
  }
  // binary search for precise estimate
  precision /= 2;
  while (precision > 0.5) {
    var before,
        after,
        beforeLength,
        afterLength,
        beforeDistance,
        afterDistance;
    if ((beforeLength = bestLength - precision) >= 0 && (beforeDistance = distance2(before = pathNode.getPointAtLength(beforeLength))) < bestDistance) {
      best = before, bestLength = beforeLength, bestDistance = beforeDistance;
    } else if ((afterLength = bestLength + precision) <= pathLength && (afterDistance = distance2(after = pathNode.getPointAtLength(afterLength))) < bestDistance) {
      best = after, bestLength = afterLength, bestDistance = afterDistance;
    } else {
      precision /= 2;
    }
  }
  best = [best.x, best.y];
  best.distance = Math.sqrt(bestDistance);
  return best;
  function distance2(p) {
    var dx = p.x - point[0],
        dy = p.y - point[1];
    return dx * dx + dy * dy;
  }
}
```

```css
.disclaimer{
  padding: 10px;
  border-left: 3px solid #ffcc00;
  background: #fffddd;
}
path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: red;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
circle {
  fill: red;
}
rect {
  fill: none;
  cursor: crosshair;
  pointer-events: all;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
<div class="disclaimer">
  This is not my own code. This is made by <a href="https://gist.github.com/mbostock/8027637">mbostock on Github</a> based on Mike Kamermans <a href="https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#projections">Primer on Bézier Curves online book</a>.
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the link, and thanks [@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/740553/mike-pomax-kamermans) for the awesome online book. I'm glad I've been stumbling across it now.

Answer (score 3):

You already know derivative of Bezier curve - it describes tangent to the curve. This tangent should be perpendicular to `QP` vector. So you need to write both components of vector `PQ` and tangent vector `T` at this point

```
PQx = (1-t)^3 * P0.x + 3*t*(1-t)^2*P1.x  ... - P.x
PQy = (1-t)^3 * P0.y + ... - P.y
Tx = 3*(1-t)^2 * (P1.x - P0.x).... and so on
Ty = ....
```

and make equation for dot product of vectors T and QP (dot product is zero for perpendicular vectors):

```
 PQx * Tx + PQy * Ty = 0
```

Now open brackets and get equation of **5-th** degree for unknown `t`.

There is no closed-form solution for such polynomial equation, so you need some kind of numerical [root-finding algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm) (use those ones intended for polynomial roots)